# ¿por que el querySelector trae múltiples datos cuando solo le envió uno?

Tags: javascript, php, html

estoy elaborando una pagina web simple que permita subir varias imágenes, la cuestión es que el ciclo para almacenar en index.js se ejecuta 2 veces por imagen, quisiera saber cual es el error o que me falta para evitar este problema.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" multiple>
        <br>
        <button type="submit">Subir</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/compressorjs/1.0.7/compressor.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

index.js

```
window.addEventListener('click', function () {

    console.log("entro")

    const form = document.querySelector('form')

    form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault()
        const files = form.querySelector('[type="file"]').files
        const promises = []
        
        console.log("entro entes del for")

        for (let file of files) {

            console.log("entro al for")

            promises.push(new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

                new Compressor(file, {
                    quality: 0.6,
                    success(result) {
                        //TODO
                    },
                    error(err) {
                        console.log(err.message)
                        reject()
                    },
                })
            }))

        }

    })

})
```

he observado que en form.addEventListene es donde hace doble el resultado, teniendo en cuenta los console.log colocados para ver el proceso, se obtiene la siguiente respuesta con solo una imagen cargada.

entro -
entro entes del for -
entro al for -
entro entes del for -
entro al for

Comment: Puede que el eventHandler se haya registrado 2 veces.

Comment: Hola Brayan, bienvenido, creo que si cambias la primer linea del js por **document.getElementById( "bot" ).addEventListener('click', function () {**, vas a evitar el doble. Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quita el evento click sobre window, literalmente se va a ejecutar un callback cada vez que clickees en cualquier lugar de la ventana y no creo que sea el resultado que esperas:

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const files = form.querySelector('[type="file"]').files;
  const promises = [];
  console.log("entro entes del for");
  for (let file of files) {
    console.log("entro al for");
    promises.push(
      new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        new Compressor(file, { quality: 0.6, success(result) { /*TODO*/ },
          error(err) {
            console.log(err.message);
            reject();
          },
        });
      })
    );
  }
  console.log(promises)
});
```

Ahí devuelve el resultado correcto, si elijo 6 archivos se generan 6 promesas y los `console.log()` dan el comportamiento esperado.